# Remote Connection Disconnect: Retrying

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying a fresh install of virtualbox, vagrant, homestead and eventually laravel. Just started on new laptop. I've set up vagrant with homestead before and didn't have a problem.

Every time I try 'vagrant up' I get that error after the SSH information. After about 4 minutes of that error repeating it will boot the machine.

The SSH info is correct. After searching the internet nothing I've found works.

Let me know if you need any other info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `config.vm.box` setting in your Vagrantfile?

Comment: Sorry forgot to close this question. I was being a noob and was vagrant up-ing from the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not booting vagrant from the correct directory. All fixed now. Thank you.